# connect to secured wireless connection using c#

Tags: c#, wireless, wep, wlanapi

I am using wlanApi class to connect to wireless connection after I scanned and found networks in my area I want to connect to them but always I get exception "profile xaml is not correct" so I try to get all connection type to xaml I found them but the problem is in password key it can't understand it and I shold but it encrypted in the profile xaml so I want WEP encrpytion code can generate the keymaterial in profile xaml from the original key how?

Comment: Hi.... I am posting this here coz I couldn't find anything like "Personal Message"! Can you please help me regarding : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497557/creating-a-wifi-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You can call WlanSetProfile on a profile that contains a plaintext key (that is, a profile with the protected element present and set to FALSE). Before the profile is saved in the profile store, the key material is automatically encrypted. When the profile is subsequently retrieved from the profile store by calling WlanGetProfile, the encrypted key material is returned."

From [this msdn api link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), from a Google search 'cause it piqued my interest.

Comment: I tried to set profile using the original key like "aaaaaaaaaa" and then get it back but I found it was not encrypted if there is some thing should I do before that please give me an example thanks