# Creating a WiFi application

Tags: c#, wifi

I have to write an Application which shares data over an Wireless Ad Hoc Network.

And I have No Idea how to do this. I am good at C# so I am thinking to choose C# for writting the Application

First question- How to read Data Received over WiFi or How to send Data over WiFi... Means is there any Port to which I should Read/Write?

Second Question- All the Protocol Management stuff is done by Adapter or my Application should that?

And also suggest some reading which I should go for! I read basics of WiFi and how it works and all!

Regards!

Comment: Do I need to Learn Socket Programming??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start reading about [Native Wifi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Windows XP SP3/Win2k/Vista/7.

Comment: Thanks for this! But I couldn't understand much.... I would be happy if I get some examples! Moreover, (From this link) I found thing called "Managed WiFi API (http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/)" but that also I couldn't understand much! I would be damn happy if I get examples or Tutorials!

Comment: There are some examples over at http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=12073

Answer (score 0):

1.you can use socket programming and get/send data with  this code.

```
            public void get_data_from_server()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            while (true)
                        {

                                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                                int r = SocClient.Receive(b);
                                if (r > 0)
                                {
                                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                                    {
                                        listBoxclient.Items.Add(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(b, 0, r));
                                        sock.Text = "socket_client == Connected";
                                        sock.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                                    });
                                }

                            Thread.Sleep(400);
                            }


                        }
                        catch
                        {

                            ;


                        }
                    }

                private void sending_client_to_server()
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            while (true)
                            {
                                string datetime = gettime();
                               string ipee =get_ip_address();
                                byte[] b = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(ipee + " : " + "5050" + "  " + datetime);
                                SocClient.Send(b);
                                delay();
                                Thread.Sleep(400);
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            ;
                        }
                    }
```

2.you can use TCP or UDP and do this.

3.you must read socket programing in C#